# VS Code Remote Python execution, all results displayed locally

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server

If it's possible to configure VScode to execute (Python in this case) on a network machine with results displayed locally, how do you set it up?

Dialogs, windows, plots, ... produced by remotely executed scripts must display on the local machine's monitors.

[In this instance, the local machine is Windows-10 and the execution machine is Fedora-38.  SSH credentials are in place - MobaXterm and VScode both connect without passwords.]